# Is there any relationship between Zuul and tox for openstack project?

Tags: openstack, tox, zuul-ci

Is there any relationship between `Zuul` and `tox` for openstack project?

When I read a [opensource openstack project](https://opendev.org/openstack/bifrost)

I find there are `zuul.d`, `bindep.txt`, `tox.ini` files.

So, the project use the zull, tox, I know them all have code review function, what's the relationship of them in there?

Answer (score 0):

No directly relationship but because openstack is a python project you are likely to see all the used as once.

- tox for running simple python tests
- bindep for installing system packages before job starts (job would not have sudo)
- zull would run the jobs

Obviously that you can install the system dependencies yourself.